# How to determine the file size of google font?

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I am using google fonts and I have included roboto font for my project and where I need to light and regular font styles, but I am unable to know what is the file size of that font.

Comment: I got the answer. My question was bit different. Actually my question was, I don't want to include the google font in project without knowing the file size. I think google is now showing the font size on there specimen of that font.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome you can open your developer tools and go to the Network tab. Click the All or CSS filter buttons and look for your CSS embed link for Google fonts. It will be something like:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed%3A300%2C400%2C700
```

If you look at the size column (right click any column to add the size column if you don't see it), you'll see a relative small file size, however this is not the size of the font itself, this is just the code that will include the font file:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Condensed Bold'), local('RobotoCondensed-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v16/ieVi2ZhZI2eCN5jzbjEETS9weq8-32meGCQYbw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

There you'll see the actual font your browser will load, `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotocondensed/v16/ieVi2ZhZI2eCN5jzbjEETS9weq8-32meGCQYbw.woff2`

Staying on the Network tab of the dev tools, click the Font filter button and now you'll see the font files themselves and their respective file sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the web inspector to see the file size of all static assets on a web page. It is under Developer Tools in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of path.